# Set height of the whole jqGrid object including the pager

Tags: javascript, jquery, layout, jqgrid

jqGrid has the method `setGridHeight` which sets the height of the grid cells only.
What I need is to set the height of the whole thing (including the pager) when the browser is resized.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do it with the following trick:

```
function setJqGridFullHeight(gridSelector,newHeight){
    $grid = $(gridSelector) ;
    $grid.setGridHeight( newHeight ) ;
    $grid.setGridHeight( 2*newHeight - $grid.closest('.ui-jqgrid').height() ) ;
}
```